# Telegram Bot URL returns 404

Tags: python, telegram-bot

I am using Python for sending message to a telegram group, the URL returns 404. Below is the code:

```
import requests
from config import API, CHAT_ID

# telegram url
url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot{}".format(API)

print(url)


def send_mess(text):
    params = {'chat_id': CHAT_ID, 'text': text}
    response = requests.post(url + 'sendMessage', data=params, timeout=20)
    return response


if __name__ == '__main__':
    d = send_mess('Hi')

    print(d)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like the `API` or the `CHAT_ID` are not well configured. Even though, I would like to suggest using the `telegram` library:

`pip install python-telegram-bot`

```
import telegram

def send_mess(text):
    token = "XXXXXX"
    chat_id = "XXXXXX"
    bot = telegram.Bot(token=token)
    bot.sendMessage(chat_id=chat_id, text=text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    d = send_mess('Hi')

    print(d)
```

Comment: Yes it worked, Can I use a similar way to send an image too?

Answer (score 0):

There's a simple typo in your code, lets take a look at the following lines:

```py
url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot{}".format(API)
...
response = requests.post(url + 'sendMessage', data=params, timeout=20)
```

This wel produce an url like;

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot123456:QWERTYsendMessage
```

Here, the url is missing an `/` between the token and the method, would recommend changing;
`url + 'sendMessage'` to `url + '/sendMessage'` to get the correct url:

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot123456:QWERTY/sendMessage
                                         ^
```

Then your code send the message as expected.